# Team City build error file not found

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, publish

I'm having an issue with a Team City build. I added a web.config transform to my publish profile however the publish process can't seem to find the file.

The file Web.Stage.config does exist on the build server in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\12d03f61c6f6df2f. Team City seems to not have added a backslash at the end of the directory path before appending the file name.

The error in full is listed below. Any help is appreciated.

Build errors

```
[15:08:47]website.publishproj.teamcity: Build target: MSDeployPublish (32s)
[15:09:03][website.publishproj.teamcity] CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy (16s)
[15:09:04][CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy] CopyPipelineFiles (15s)
[15:09:19][CopyPipelineFiles] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2709, 5): Copying file C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\12d03f61c6f6df2fWeb.CRIStage.config to binobj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Web.CRIStage.config failed. Could not find file 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\12d03f61c6f6df2fWeb.Stage.config'.
[15:09:20][website.publishproj.teamcity] Project website.publishproj.teamcity failed.
```

Comment: Can you please post the content of the TeamCity configuration which specifies the content to publish after build?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around you can give 'Artifacts Path' in your 'General Settings' tab of Build Configuration as `\Web.Stage.config` by adding a slash before the file name. So that it will take the file path properly as `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\12d03f61c6f6df2f\Web.Stage.config`.